# How do I sumit a email and then press "submit" button

Tags: c#

[Sorry for my terrible spelling]
I'm working on a windows form application where the user inputs their email into a textbox and I save it as a variable After which I need to automatically open an incognito browser window to a website and input the email in to the email address bar and then click a submit button. The email bar has an id but the button does not. I tryed using an example from the internet and don't know what "webBrowser1" is, it gives me an error "the name webBrowser1 does not exist in the current context". It needs to be an incognito window so history and cookies don't get affected.

```cs
    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var email = this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("chrome.exe", "-incognito " + "url");
            HtmlElement  link = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("newsletter_email");
            link.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
```

Comment: So, I think what you're looking for is how to make a request? Don't need to open a browser for that. Google for it.

Comment: I have the feeling you copied code from somewhere. You are starting an external process (outside the realm of your code) and then trying to access a local web browser control for data. It would be like opening Word and asking Notepad to do a search. You need to add a web browser control to your form and direct that to the URL, not an external process.

Comment: webBrowser1 is currently undefined, It might be your current Browser instance. Or your new browser instance, that you have to invoke.